# How to switch between Linux virtual terminals over serial?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen, serial-port, virtual-terminal

How do you switch between Linux [virtual terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) over a serial terminal connection?

I'm trying to install [Debian on a Beagleboard](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardDebian) via the serial console.  I'm using [`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (`screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`)  in [Gnome Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal) as my terminal emulator.  Unfortunately the primary `debian-installer` text interface goes unresponsive during the install, though I'm pretty sure it still has a couple of virtual terminals open with `dmesg`-type info that I could use to troubleshoot.

I've tried Alt+F[1-7], but those seem to get consumed by Gnome Terminal or my window manager.  Ctrl+Alt+F[1-7] are consumed by my local system, as are Alt+F[1-7] when I switch away from X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial connections do not have virtual terminals. If you need to have more than one application running via a serial connection then you will need to use `screen`.

Comment: To expand, "virtual" terminals are displayed on the host itself and only *emulate* a serial terminal.  A serial terminal is a "real" terminal, not virtual.

Comment: Quoting: "then you will need to use `screen`." Or just another serial line.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
sudo chvt 2
```

to switch to virtual terminal 2, for example.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533539/switch-tabs-in-debian-installer-over-serial-console-with-putty).

In short, the installer is probably using GNU screen, so `Ctrl+a`, `2`.  If you have a nested GNU screen then `Ctrl+a`, `a`, `2`.  Use different numbers to switch to terminals other than number 2.